# How to remove Question mark from Title from Workflow Dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow

I am showing `WorkflowElementDialog` from my application, this dialog box having a question mark beside close button. is there a way to remove it?

Xaml Code

```
<sap:WorkflowElementDialog x:Class="SqlEditorDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
        xmlns:sapc="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
        xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
        Title="{x:Static p:Resources.EditSql}">

</sap:WorkflowElementDialog>
```

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am showing WorkflowElementDialog from my application, this dialog box having a question mark beside close button. is there a way to remove it?

---

I am afraid there's **no built in way to remove the question mark** from the title area; this actually is called a context help button. When you call `Show` or an instance is created, it will create a new instance of a `WorkflowElementDialogWindow` This class has a routine called `OnInitialized` which set's some properties as well as call the base class it derives from called `DialogWindow` and then calls `OnSourceInitialized()`. In this routine is where the actual context button is created, here's what it looks like.

```
 protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
 {
      base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
      this.HideMinMaxButton();
      this.ShowContextHelpButton(); // Here's the culprit.
      this.HideIcon();
      this.AddWindowsHook(new HwndSourceHook(DialogWindow.OnHookedWindowMessage));
      base.get_CommandBindings().Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.get_Help(), new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(this.OnHelpExecuted)));
      base.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(this.OnWindowClosing);
 }
```

One option is to re-create the classes, then you can leave out the `ShowContextHelpButton` routine; but this would require a little work and some source browsing to do.

References:

[**WorkflowElementDialog** Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities.Presentation/System.Activities.Presentation/System/Activities/Presentation/WorkflowElementDialog.cs,115)

Comment: OnSourceInitialized(eventargs): no suitable method found to override getting this error after adding the code

Comment: @madan please re-read my post. That snippet is in a class you dont have access to.